# How to properly encode HTML within XML in PHP for SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap, character-encoding

I'm attempting to communicate with Exchange 2007, and there are known bugs/problems with doing UpdateItem() so I'm manually communicating over cURL, building my own XML instead of letting the SOAP client do it. It all works fine, but I need to be able to properly encode HTML to fit within the elements of XML.

I know about html_encode() and htmlspecialchars() but I am unsure whether or not these are proper to use and whether or not in the future it may not encode correctly, and screw up the SOAP communication.

As a side note, if it matters, the communication will be in both English and Russian, so it needs to be Unicode safe.

Comment: Isn't [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect) an option here?

Comment: I'm not sure, I can't seem to find any examples of CDATA being used with Exchange 2007 SOAP.

Comment: What about XHTML, or just well-formed HTML?

Comment: It's updating calendar event information in Exchange which is HTML 4.01, even then it has to be encoded. Like <br> to &gt;br&lt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html_encode will use HTML entities. HTML entities are defined for HTML, but not for XML, so this won't work.

Escaping tags in XML is done by wrapping your content in [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tags. Special characters (üéâä) can be represented in UTF8.

Comment: nitpicks: `htmlspecialchars` would work tough. Wrapping the content into CDATA tags is not "escaping".

Comment: After a lot of searching and testing, htmlspecialchars actually seems to work, but Exchange doesn't seem to like CDATA in the particular elements I've attempted to use it in.